# Angular multi lang build process for assets path

Tags: angular

I'm finally learning angular (v17) after playing with angularJS for a while. I'm building a muli lang application and when running **ng build --localize** I get :

dist/browser/fr/assets

dist/browser/en/assets

which is totally absurd because assets are the same and quite heavy in size so not optimized at all !

I've tried the advanced assets configuration options (https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration) but all copied files are always inside dist/browser/LANG instead of being at the same level that LANG :

```
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/img",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/webp/",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
```

Any help or advices are welcome !